# Which address &self point to?

Tags: objective-c, pointers, self

I'm trying to understand Objective-C runtime and don't figure out, where `self` pointer is pointing to. I wrote an example to check what `&self` will show. I've create `ClassA` as shown below:

```
@implementation ClassA
   -(void) print {
       NSLog(@"Class A &self is: %p", &self);
   }
@end
```

Then I created two instances of `A` at `main()` and call `printf()` to print it out:

```
ClassA *firstInstance = [ClassA new];
[firstInstance print];

ClassA *secondInstance = [ClassA new];
[secondInstance print];
```

And I get the same addresses for both instances:

```
Class A &self is: 0x7fff5bacf4e8
Class A &self is: 0x7fff5bacf4e8
```

Even more when I created a second class with following code:

```
@implementation ClassA
-(void) print {
    NSLog(@"Class B &self is: %p", &self);
}
@end
```

I get the same address at `&self`.

```
Class B &self is: 0x7fff5bacf4e8
```

Why the `&self` always points to same address?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`self` points to the object that received the message. But you do not print `self`. You print `&self` what is a pointer *to* `self`, not the pointee of `self`.

```
&self -> self -> object
```

Since `self` is silently passed to every method, you simply print out the address of the argument on the stack, which is always the same in your case regardless of the instance or type `self` points to.

To print out the address, `self` points to, simply delete the `&`.

Comment: It should likely be noted that the reason this even happens in this case is that it's taking the address of `self` as it is on the stack _within the execution of `-print`_. Calling `-print` pushes a new stack frame onto the stack, and `self` is placed on top of it. `&self != &a != &b`; `a` and `b` are at different stack locations, but `self` is separate even from those. If you called `-print` from inside a different function, `&self` would be different still

Comment: I do not know, whether it is worth noting, why something happens in a specific way, if the OP doesn't want to do this at all. ;-)

Comment: Sure, but for education's sake... Someone who is not OP might stumble upon this question and wonder. But, just my opinion and why I left the reasoning as a comment and not an edit or another answer. :)

Comment: An edit would clearly conflict with the author's intent. (I know him, because I shave his face every day.) ;-) But, of course, you are right: Someone might have this additional Q.

Answer (score 1):

In every method, `self` is a hidden parameter. A parameter of a function is a local variable, so `-print` is simply printing the address of its own local variable in that particular call of itself. It has nothing to do with the object it is called on.

The two calls you make right after each other from the same function in your example happen to print the same thing because each call will put a new stack frame on top of the (same) current stack frame, and the location of the local variable `self` in `-print`'s stack frame is fixed, so the locations will be the same.